# Why is the destructor called after assignment?

Tags: c++, c++03

Why is destructor being called here after the line `mystring = "Hello, there!";`
It is not like it is going out of scope yet. I am definitely missing some quirk of C++!

I know that line calls the default copy constructor, is the destructor always called after a copy constructor returns?

Just as a side note, I am using C++03, no C++11 yet.

**EDIT :** Also please note that I am aware of the double deletion that this below program causes. I am experimenting here. Just wanted to bring to your notice.

```
class MyString
{
private:
    char* mystring;
    int m_length;
public:

    MyString(const char* str="")
    {
        assert(str);
        m_length = strlen(str) + 1;
        mystring = new char[m_length];
        for (int i = 0; i < m_length; ++i)
            mystring[i] = str[i];
        mystring[m_length-1] = '\0';
    }

    ~MyString()
    {
        delete[] mystring;
    }

};

int main()
{
   MyString mystring("");
   mystring = "Hello, there!";
   cout << "Destructor not yet called ";
}
```

Comment: What were the conclusions you came to when you ran through a debugger?

Comment: Compiler generates implicit copy assignment operator. Your object got assigned from a temporal object the compiler created (because you have a non-explicit single argument constructor (aka converting constructor)); Its that temporal object that gets destructed. And secondly, your program is buggy

Comment: how do you know that the destructor is called?

Comment: I was debugging and see that after the line `mystring = "Hello, there!"` destructor is hit, and wait, again after main() is returned it is hit ( this makes sense ) but not the first hit.

Comment: *I am definitely missing some quirk of C++!* -- More than just a "quirk" you're missing.  This program produces a double-deletion error `{MyString m1; MyString m2=m1;}`,

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes it produces double-deletion , I am trying to understand what is causing the destructor to be hit before it comes out of`main()`

Comment: @svasa -- Read up on the copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: Read up on the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you do not have a assignment operator for your class which takes a string literal `mystring = "Hello, there!";` is turned into a 3 part operation.

- First it has to construct a temporary object from the string literal.
- Then it takes that temporary and uses it with the default copy(pre C++11)/move(post C++11 if not deleted otherwise) assignment operator the compiler generated for the class.
- Then it has to destroy the temporary object that it created.  That is why you would see a call to the destructor at the end of that expression.

---

Do note that since the temporary object is destroyed after

```
mystring = "Hello, there!";
```

That the pointer `mystring` holds is now deleted and you can no longer access it.  It will also cause a double deletion when it is destroyed which is undefined behavior and will cause complications.

Comment: I am not wrong, then the `myString` is in total deleted twice and the `mystring` is useless already after it has been constructed.

Comment: `Then it has to destroy the temporary object that it created` - this is the part I am missing. Thanks. And one question, compiler always deletes temporary objects that it creates while using copy constructors ?

Comment: @tobi303 You are not wrong that `myString` has a double delete but it appears the OP is aware of that so I did not mention it.

Comment: @svasa Yeah, all temporary objects generated by the compiler in an expression are destroyed at the end of the full expression.

Comment: Err... is deleting a string literal even a defined behavior?

Comment: as I understood OP was aware that there is some sort of double delete, but I am not 100% sure if OP is aware that already after `mystring = "Hello, there!";` the `mystring` is garbage.

Comment: @WhiZTiM They never delete the literal.  The `const char*` constructor `new`'s up memory and copies the literal into that.

Comment: @tobi303 Ah.  I included that into the answer to make sure they understand that.

Comment: you already had my upvote, I was just fascinated about learning just another way to think you shoot yourself in the foot when in reality you blew both legs away ;)